# Plot data on World/Country map

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I want to visualize some plot data on world or country maps. I have found this one [DIY Map](http://backspace.com/mapapp/), but the map is in Flash only.

Has anyone some similar free maps, but developed only in JavaScript?

Answer (score 6):

I would, if I may, suggest to check out [Highmaps](http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo), from the people behind [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com) (myself included). It's free for non-commercial use, works great with mobile browsers (full touch support) and old IE down to IE6. It supports advanced dynamic features like drilldown and rich tooltips, and is very customizable.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about Map Charts from Google Charts: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/new_map_charts.html

With Google Charts you create a URL based on your data.  That URL will go into an img object and google will render the map for you.   You can programatically change it by setting a new URL with new parameters.

Comment: This service is hosted, and Google has recently removed services that a lot of people were using. Risky!

Comment: Yeap.   Let's not use GMail, or Google Docs, because they are free and 'Google has recently removed services that a lot of people were using. Risky!'

@Steinbitglis: Your downvote discourages people to offer proposals that the asker could use to evaluate.  And your argument is weak in my opinion.

Comment: Try something that is not hosted, and developed only in JavaScript. Giving up-votes for poor answers is not the right way to encourage people to write proposals.

Comment: You are entitled to your opinions.  I simply disagree with them, and I think your argument is not valid. A hosted solution is a good solution for certain situations and not for others. But not sharing it because it **may** be a bad solution for certain situations is silly.   That is where I disagree with you and think your argument is wrong.  But hey, that is me and you can do as you please.   That is the beauty of this site.

Comment: This is what we get in year 2017: @Warning: This API is deprecated.@ So, what do you think now?